# How to give settings(alpha value for background view) in SideMenu in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alpha, side-menu

I’m using left side menu from [jonkykong/SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) this framework. Here i need to change background view colour alpha value while open(means click on button) the side menu and when i close the side menu i need back the original background colour.
for that I have tried two methods:

**Method 1):**

```
  func sidemenuOpenCloseColorChang(){

    let menu = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UISideMenuNavigationController") as! UISideMenuNavigationController
    var set = SideMenuSettings()
    set.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
    set.presentationStyle = SideMenuPresentationStyle.menuSlideIn
    set.presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 0.5

    set.menuWidth = min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height) * 0.90
    //menu.sideMenuManager.addScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.view)
    menu.settings = set
    //SideMenuManager.default.addScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: view)
    SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = menu
}
```

getting below error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'SideMenuSettings'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'SideMenuPresentationStyle'
>
> Value of type 'SideMenuManager' has no member 'leftMenuNavigationController'

**Method 2):** using UISideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate Metod

```
@IBAction func sideMenubtn(_ sender: Any) {
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
}

extension ProfileViewController : UISideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate {
private func sideMenuWillDisappear(menu: UISideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate, animated: Bool) {
//*do the color thing*
    print("sidemenu disappear")
view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Nothing worked for me, please help me in this code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me like you didn't properly import your SideMenu dependency. Your compiler isn't recognizing `SideMenuSettings`, and it's saying that `SideMenuManager` doesn't have a property called `leftMenuNavigationController`. It's hard to do much with this without seeing your project setup.

Comment: which library used for sideMenu?